# Nokia X(1.2.4.1 & platforms 1.2) is not recognized by eclipse

Tags: eclipse, nokiax

I have updated my Nokia X in new update official (1.2.4.1 & platforms 1.2) update is ok BUT, when i connected my phone on my Eclipse, it is not recognized . Before updating every thing was fine. Please Help

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any problems in there. Anyway you could check the documentation on how you can get your device connected, and re-try the steps.

Though, before you try, do check from device manager whether it is showing errors from there, and whether you could fix the issues from there. By for example, re-installing the driver.

Answer (score 0):

Try using hacked drivers from here: http://forum.xda-developers.com/nokia-x/general/fix-updated-adb-drivers-nokia-x-v1-2-4-1-t2835827/